# Copy from one sheet to another from designated folder with a specific date value in the file name

Tags: excel, vba, filenames

I am trying to copy value from one tab and paste to another excel file.

Source file was saved in the destination file saved in
"D:\Feb 2023\20230214\Daily Rec 20230214.xlsb"
and destination file saved in
"D:\Feb 2023\20230214\Daily Rec 20230214.xlsb"

I am wonder if I can input Month and date value in the destination file to make the macro smart enough to go for the newly saved files (normally saved by month and date)

For example, in the designation file Sheet "Rec", Cell"A1", input is "Feb 2023", and Cell"B1", input is "20230214". Can I make the filenames taken the value from these 2 cells?

Thank you.

```
Sub LoadJPMTrans()
Const csvFile = "D:\Feb 2023\20230214\JPM Statement_MTD_20230214.xls"
Dim ws As Worksheet, csv As Workbook, cCount As Long, cName As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet          
Workbooks.Open csvFile                     
Set csv = ActiveWorkbook

Filename = "D:\Feb 2023\20230214\Daily Rec 20230214.xlsb"

cName = csv.Name                           
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Details").Columns("A:AH").Copy            

Workbooks.Open Filename

Set test = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("JPM Statement")
test.Activate
test.Range("A:AH").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  
csv.Close                                 

End Sub
```

Comment: The 2 paths in the first part of the description looks the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows how to read a date from a cell, and use that date to create a file path:

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook, wsRec As Worksheet, dt As Date, ymd As String, my As String
Dim csvFile As String, fileName As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsRec = wb.Worksheets("Rec")

dt = wsRec.Range("A1").Value 'read the date (only need one cell)
my = Format(dt, "Mmm yyyy")  'format as (eg) "Feb 2023"
ymd = Format(dt, "yyyymmdd") 'format as (eg) "20230214"

csvFile = "D:\" & my & "\" & ymd & "\JPM Statement_MTD_" & ymd & ".xls"
Debug.Print csvFile

fileName = "D:\" & my & "\" & ymd & "\Daily Rec " & ymd & ".xlsb"
Debug.Print fileName
```

`Format` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications